# ERROR: CATTLE_URL cannot contain localhost or 127.0.0.1, please check the Host Registration URL

Tags: url, rancher, cattle

When I try to add custom host for Rancher server it gives ERROR: CATTLE_URL cannot contain localhost or 127.0.0.1, please check the Host Registration URL.

Answer (score 3):

just don't use localhost or 127.0.0.1 :( for your rancher host registration url (in rancher server / admin / settings)

1. find your real ip (for mac ifconfig ...)
2. change host registration URL to founded IP (in rancher server / admin / settings menu)
3. copy register script (in rancher server / infrastructure / hosts / add hosts / custom)
4. run your script in CLI